# Concatenando duas listas ligadas em C

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou iniciando meus estudos sobre estruturas dinâmicas em *C* e estou com problemas em fazer um código para concatenar duas listas. A parte de pintar na tela o conteúdo das listas esta funcionando, mas na hora de concatenar aparece

> ```
> "Segmentation fault: 11"...
> ```

Fiquem a vontade para dar sugestões sobre outras partes do código.

**Segue o código:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedNode LinkedNode;
struct LinkedNode{
int data;
LinkedNode* next;
};

LinkedNode* concatena(LinkedNode* lis1, LinkedNode* lis2){

LinkedNode* tmp1 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));

if(lis1==NULL){
return lis2;
}

if(lis2==NULL){
return lis1;
}

if(lis1!=NULL && lis2!=NULL){
while(lis1!=NULL){
tmp1 = lis1;
lis1 = lis1->next;
}
tmp1->next = lis2;
}

return tmp1;
}

void printList(LinkedNode* curr){
while(curr!=NULL){
    printf("%d ", curr->data);
    curr = curr->next;
}

printf("\n");
}

int main(){

LinkedNode* first1 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
LinkedNode* second1 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
LinkedNode* first2 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
LinkedNode* second2 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
LinkedNode* last1 = NULL;
LinkedNode* last2 = NULL;

first1->data = 1;
first1->next = second1;
second1->data = 2;
second1->next = NULL;
last1 = second1;

first2->data = 3;
first2->next = second2;
second2->data = 4;
second2->next = NULL;
last2 = second2;

printf("Lista 1: ");
printList(first1);
printf("Lista 2: ");
printList(first2);

free(first1);
free(first2);
free(second1);
free(second2);

printList(concatena(first1, first2));

return 0;

}//fecha o programa
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe esse trecho:

```
if(lis1==NULL){
return lis2;
}

if(lis2==NULL){
return lis1;
}

if(lis1!=NULL && lis2!=NULL){
```

Ora, se uma das duas for `NULL`, um desses dois `return`s já terá sido atingido, e portanto, esse terceiro `if` é desnecessário, pois é impossível ele ser atingindo quando a condição dele for falsa.

Entretanto, há um erro de *memory leak* aqui, pois imediatamente antes temos isso:

```
LinkedNode* tmp1 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
```

Se essa alocação de memória for feita com alguma das listas sendo `NULL`, esse nó alocado não será colocado em lugar nenhum e a referência a ele será perdida sem que a memória alocada por ele seja liberada. Entretanto, ao analisar a lógica dessa função, você não precisa alocara nada, e essa alocação está aí de bobeira, pois o `tmp1 = lis1;` dentro do `while` mais abaixo vai garantir que que o que foi alocado antes será perdido. A solução é simplesmente não alocar nada.

Nessa função você ainda faz uma boa bagunça com os ponteiros `tmp1` e `lis1`, bagunçando as listas e perdendo alguns nós.

Finalmente, na função `main`, você vai chamar o `printList` usando nós que correspondem à memória que já foi desalocada com `free`. Nunca utilize um ponteiro que já foi repassado à `free`. A solução é colocar o `free` apenas no final.

No `main`, você também não precisa (ao menos não ainda) de `last1` e `last2`.

Como última dica, ressalto que cultivar uma disciplina de manter uma identação rigorosa e não se tolerar os mínimos desvios é bom porque vai evitar enganos e confusões na escrita e na leitura do código.

Segue o código revisado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedNode LinkedNode;
struct LinkedNode {
    int data;
    LinkedNode* next;
};

LinkedNode* concatena(LinkedNode* lis1, LinkedNode* lis2) {
    if (lis1 == NULL) return lis2;
    if (lis2 == NULL) return lis1;

    LinkedNode* tmp1 = lis1;
    while (lis1 != NULL) {
        lis1 = lis1->next;
    }
    lis1->next = lis2;

    return tmp1;
}

void printList(LinkedNode* curr) {
    while (curr != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    LinkedNode* first1 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    LinkedNode* second1 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    LinkedNode* first2 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    LinkedNode* second2 = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));

    first1->data = 1;
    first1->next = second1;
    second1->data = 2;
    second1->next = NULL;

    first2->data = 3;
    first2->next = second2;
    second2->data = 4;
    second2->next = NULL;

    printf("Lista 1: ");
    printList(first1);
    printf("Lista 2: ");
    printList(first2);

    printList(concatena(first1, first2));

    free(first1);
    free(first2);
    free(second1);
    free(second2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Lista* concatList(Lista* a, Lista* b){

    Lista* temp = a;
    while(temp != NULL){
        b = inserirFim(b, temp->item);
        temp = temp->prox;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Explique melhor sua resposta...